# How to 'call' a procedure from an algorithm in algorithm2e?

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithm2e

I am using `algorithm2e` and I wrote a `Procedure` and an `Algorithm`. I want to call the procedure in the algorithm. All I have to reference the procedure is its `\label{proc:myproc}`.

```
\begin{procedure}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\tcc*[l]{Procedure}
 \SetAlgoLined
 \KwIn{Input}
 \KwOut{Output}
Initial step 1\;
Initial step 2\;
    \ForEach{}{
    \ForEach{}{
    \tcc*[l]{Do this}\;
    }
    }
%
\caption{Compute this()} \label{proc:myproc}
\end{procedure}
```

So I can do this in the algorithm: `\ref{proc:myproc}`. But this referencing gives me the plain text `Compute this`. Is there another kind of referencing that I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which kind of reference are you looking for? If you want to call the procedure, isn't it the name of the procedure that you want to use?